# .htaccess redirect entire subdomain but one directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am creating a multi lingual site organized in subdomain. I have en, fr and es.
At the moment es is not yet finished so I am redirecting everything to the old website but I would like to make some sections available.
This is my code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^es\.domain\.org$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^ccc
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.org/es [R=302,L]
```

But it does not work. When I try es.domain.org/ccc I go to http://www.domain.org/es .
Any suggestion? Thanks

**EDIT:** I tried also to use the skip flag, without success:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/ccc/(.*)$
RewriteRule .? - [S=1]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^es.domain.org$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.org/es [R=302,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ru.domain.org$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.org/ru [R=302,L]
```

but it does not work either. In this case when on page ccc (I am using Drupal) we should skip the first rule and apply the second. As a test if I visit es.domain.org/ccc nothing should happen, If I visit ru.domain.org/ccc or whatever else I should be redirected to http://www.domain.org/ru or /es. But it does not work.

Comment: Try `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ccc`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this negative lookahead based rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^es\.domain\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!ccc).*)$ http://www.domain.org/es/$1 [R=302,L,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks @anubhava, unfortunately, for some strange reasons, it does not work. I also tried the form:  
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^es\.domain\.org$ [NC]  
 RewriteRule ^(?!ccc)(.*) http://www.domain.org/es [R=302,L,NC]`  
to catch subdirectories without success.

Comment: For which URL it didn't work? Ate there more rules in this htaccess?

Comment: it seems that it is simply ignored. The rule is third. The first rule send to 443 all "edit traffic" the second works fine. Here are rules 2 and 3: `## SPANISH
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^es\.domain\.org$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/ddd/d1(.*)$
  RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.org/es/d1_old [R=302,L]

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^es\.domain\.org$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(?!123ccc)(.*) http://www.domain.org/es [R=302,L,NC]`

Comment: Make this rule as first rule just below `RewriteEngine On` line and also you must `$1` in target as shown in my answer `http://www.domain.org/es/$1`